# Why is the Action Chaining in Struts2 not recommended?

Tags: struts2, chaining

What makes [Action Chaining](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/action-chaining.html) in Struts2 a bad idea?

The link above suggests using Redirect After Post, via Redirect Result or Redirect Action Result. Is Redirect Action the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in that link itself
If chaining is overused, an application can turn into "[spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)".

As far as I understand there is no performance issue with this.